# Remove shared prefrences Android

Tags: android, android-intent

On click of a button i want to remove the data that i have store on Login Activity.I have to remove this from diffrent activity how can we delete this .

This is how i have saved the values.

```
public void saveInformation(String username, String password) {
        SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("SelfTrip", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
        editor.putString("username", username);
        editor.putString("password", password);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: here is a tutorial about how to use `SharedPreferences` , clear entries , update entries, retreive entries : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/using-sharedpreferences-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
                     SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("SelfTrip",
                             MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
                        editor.clear();
                        editor.commit(); 
                        finish();

                }
```

Comment: this will finish your current activity

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wanted, this will clear all shared preference values, I believe he only wants to clear the username and password values

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all entries from your shared preferences file with the following:

```
getSharedPreferences("SelfTrip",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

And this is how you can **delete values** from the SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Mypref", 0);

Editor e = preferences.edit();
e.remove("yourkey");
e.commit();
```

Simply use the `remove()` method of the Editor and remove a value with your key.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a value from SharedPreferences use the `remove()` method with the appropriate key (e.g. username):

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("SelfTrip", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();    
editor.remove("username").commit();
```